# Add tick mark (✔) to string.xml

Tags: android, unicode

I am adding tick mark (✔) on a string message on the `strings.xml`, but I am getting  a "box" instead of the tick mark when I am display that on the mobile device.

I have directly pasted the symbol on my string message.

Is there any way we can handle that? Do we need to use an unicode value?

Comment: I am using the string for a toast message display.

Answer (score 41):

Add unicode symbol `"\u2713"` to your string resource or you can use it from code as String object.

```
String checkedMark = "\u2713";
```

Comment: i don't know why but it show "." in my simulator :-D

Comment: Perfect, Like Right Icon display :)

Answer (score 9):

Try using `&#x2713;` as the string value, then use `Html.fromHtml` to parse the string.

Comment: &#1004; is Ϭ, not checkmark.
the correct one is &#x2713;

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using an unicode value, I would also recommend you to use a `Drawable` inside a `TextView`. For example, you can add the drawable to the `TextView` using [android:drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to get a Spannable text and set it to your text view. In string.xml you will specify the corresponding HTML entity such as `&gt;`