# changing BulletSpan icon in Android

Tags: android, textview, bullet-span

I am using BulletSpan(BulletSpan.STANDARD_GAP_WIDTH)

How can I change its icon from a circle to ✓?

```
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(text+"\n");
    s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(BulletSpan.STANDARD_GAP_WIDTH), 0, text.length(), 0);
```

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579780/add-tick-mark-to-string-xml

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to style the bullet icon used by Android but didn't find any answers online.  I ended up using an alternative approach which may help you further as well.

I didn't use BulletSpan but I used LeadingMarginSpan instead. You can add whatever character you want as icon (such as your tick character) in the text to be "spanned". By setting the first line margin and rest margins correctly you can achieve the same effect as the BulletSpan.